# Notepad++ How to replace everything in between certain lines

Tags: regex, replace, find, notepad++

So I have a code like this

```
TitleManager:AddSubTitleMissionInfo_LUA({
  m_iID = 10,
  m_wstrDescription = "Professional Killer",
  m_eClearType = TITLE_MISSION_CLEAR_TYPE.TMCT_MOB_KILL_COUNT,
  m_bAutomaticDescription = True,
  m_ClearCondition = {
    m_eMobID = {68},
    m_iMobKillCount = {1}
  }
})
TitleManager:AddSubTitleMissionInfo_LUA({
  m_iID = 20,
  m_wstrDescription = "Sneaky Assassin",
  m_eClearType = TITLE_MISSION_CLEAR_TYPE.TMCT_MOB_KILL_COUNT,
  m_bAutomaticDescription = True,
  m_ClearCondition = {
    m_eMobID = {69},
    m_iMobKillCount = {1}
  }
})
TitleManager:AddSubTitleMissionInfo_LUA({
  m_iID = 20,
  m_wstrDescription = "Merciless Thug",
  m_eClearType = TITLE_MISSION_CLEAR_TYPE.TMCT_MOB_KILL_COUNT,
  m_bAutomaticDescription = True,
  m_ClearCondition = {
    m_eMobID = {70,71},
    m_iMobKillCount = {1,1}
  }
})
```

There are like a hundred of those, all different.
How do I replace everything in between the curly brackets.

```
m_ClearCondition = {

}
```

to

```
m_ClearCondition = {
m_eMobID = {50},
m_iMobKillCount = {1}
}
```

I really hope someone could answer my question, I would be really grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Description

There are several unclear things about your sample text from your post. But this expression assumes:

- each `m_clearcondition` value will have no nested brackets more then one level deep.
- will find each key name m_clearcondition and place that into capture group 1
- the close bracket will be captured into group 2

Regex:

```
^(\s+m_ClearCondition\s*=\s*\{)(?:\{[^}]*\}|[^}])*(\})
```

Replace with:

```
$1\n    m_eMobID = {50},\n    m_iMobKillCount = {1}\n  $2
```

## Example:

Live demo of the regex: http://regexr.com?35n0l

[image]

In this example I'm using Notepad++ 6.4.2. There where known problems using regex in Notepad version 5 and lower.

Answer (score 0):

Regex is your friend. Ctrl-H (Find/replace) and enable regular expressions (bottom left of dialog).

```
\{\s*\}$
```

replace with:

```
{\nwhatever you want\n}\n
```

Regex Match Explanation:

- {} are reserved, so escaping them will match the actual brace character
- \s of course will match all whitespace (including new lines and tabs)
- $ would be the end of the line; this just helps the match
- \n in the replace would insert new lines where it makes sense; these are optional.

Comment: I tried this and it only replaced the ones that were blank, how do I include the ones with codes written inside the curly brackets.

Comment: @user2201461: You need to specify exactly what content may be encountered between those curly braces.